# public static files are not accesible when deployed in vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vercel

I have simple html file which i got access by using https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions

```
filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), "public/index.html");
```

But this `index.html` has some ref of `css` files and `svgs` , which vercel is still not able to access.
How can i get it ?

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styleguide.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="card col">
                <img
                    class="logo"
                    src="svg/logo/stackoverflow-logo.svg"
                    alt="Stack Overflow Logo"
                />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Project Structure

[image]

I guess some equivalent to the below in `vercel.json` I need to setup.

```
const staticMiddleware = express.static("public", {
    extensions: ["html", "css", "js", "svg"],
});
app.use(staticMiddleware);
```